# Binary search in react native how to?

Tags: react-native

I need to ask user "Is your number higher than 50?"/ or 2 buttons with "Higher" ... "Lower".
So then i need to realize binary search.
I tried to make it in js with arrays, so it is works, but I can't do it in native.

Comment: the logic for the binary search is same everywhere. What do you mean by you can't do it in native?

Comment: I am not talking only about logic. I just can't realize that, bcz things like "confirm" in js, don't work in react native. I tried to realize it by Alert.alert(), but it is don't work idk why.

Comment: Then you might want to look into how to show an alert in react-native.

Comment: Idk is the alerts/only alerts reason of the problem or not.